# Assign values in large scale into a data base. Formula (libreOffice calc)

Tags: excel, relational-database, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to create a data base in libreOffice spreed-sheet application. And what I need is, the first column to be Id's, but each Id has to fill 100 cells. So I would like to have 2000 Id's and each Id takes up 100 cells, we have 200 000 cells. (Id's values = range(1,2000))

> row#1 : row#100 = Id#1 // row#101 : row#200 = Id#2 ....// row#199900 : row#200000 = Id#2000

What I simply want is to assign the value `1` to the first 100 cells in the first column, the value `2` to the next 100 cells in the same column and so on, until I have the 2000 Id's in the first column.

So I would like to find a formula to achieve that with out having to select and scroll manually 2000 times the sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is in A column:

```
=QUOTIENT(ROW(A1);100)+1
```

The formula adds 1 to integer part of the number of row divided by 100.

Comment: OK, the formula is great.. but how can I now apply that for the 200 000 cells in column A? with out dragging? sorry I am very newbie with spreed-sheets

Comment: If you're new I suggest going to the cell number 200000 - you can go there quickly by writing A200000 in the field that shows your current selection. When you're there write down your formula, go to A1 with Ctrl + Shift + Up to select all cells from 1 to 200000 and click on the formula bar then press Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: Ok what I did was, write down the formula in the cell number one. Then pres enter and select all cells down until 200000 with Ctrl + Shift + Up. One I have selected all cells I just press Ctrl  + D. It works

Comment: Glad to hear that, if this is the answer that you decided to go with, please select it.

Answer (score 1):

Apply with a loop?

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 2000
        Range("A1:A100").Offset((i - 1) * 100, 0) = i
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, sorry I am very newbie withs spreed-sheets. Where I supposed have to write a loop in the application? I just know to add some formulas.. but that's all.. Thanks

Comment: https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.1/HTML/GS5113-GettingStartedWithMacros.html